# Entity framework database-first approach stored procedure with output parameter and result set

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am using database-first approach for Entity Framework in my ASP.NET project. I have a stored procedure that has an output parameter `@TotalCount` and it returns a result set using a `SELECT` statement.

When I add the stored procedure in my `MyDbContext.edmx` file, the `MyDbContext.cs` has a function that returns an int (probably the output parameter) that is automatically generated for the stored procedure.

How can I access both the output parameter as well as the result set with this approach?

The stored procedure snippet is given below. Basically I am trying to do pagination in the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetDetailsForStudent]
    @StudentId BIGINT,
    //....
    @OrderBy NVARCHAR(max),
    @Page INT OUTPUT,
    @Items INT = 200,
    @TotalCount INT OUTPUT
    //.....

    SET @SortSql = N'SELECT * FROM #tmpTable'
    //......    
    EXEC sp_executesql @SortSql;
```

In the `MyDbContext.cs` file

```
 public virtual int sp_GetDetailsForStudent(parameters ...){
     //......
     return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("sp_GetDetailsForStudent", input parameters..., totalCount);
 }
```

Comment: Hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881359/i-cannot-get-the-output-parameter-when-use-function-import-by-entity-framework/7183184#7183184) will help you.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update your EDMX model so that your function

```
public virtual int sp_GetDetailsForStudent(parameters ...){....}
```

Should look like

```
public virtual ObjectResult<YourResult_type> sp_GetDetailsForStudent(parameters ...){....}
```

For refreshing EDMX model go [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995226/refreshing-a-stored-procedure-in-entity-framework-3-5)

You might need to choose **"Create New Complex Type"** option instead of **"Update"** as suggested in above link.

Then to fetch the result you can use below code

```
ObjectParameter outParam1 = new ObjectParameter("outParameter", typeof(long));
var db = new YourDbContext();
var res = db.sp_GetDetailsForStudent(parameter1,parameter2,outParam1 );
foreach (YourResult_type item in res)
{
    var prop1= item.property1;
}
var outParam1Value= outParam1.Value;
```